# How to Change Axis Tick Labels in dynamic tkinter chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a chart on a canvas in matplotlib that will be changed fairly frequently, and I am unable to change axis labels, instead I just get the default numerical labels on the major gridlines. Here is a simplified example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#import matplotlib.animation as animation
#from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

def customplot(f):
    try:
        f.clf()
        #plt.clf()
        #ax.clear()
        #f.delaxes(ax)
    except:
        None
    try:
        ax=ax
    except:
        ax=f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(np.random.uniform(size=3),np.random.uniform(size=3))
    plt.xticks([1,2,3],['one','two','three']) #THIS LINE!!!!???

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.canvas1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f,self.master)
        self.updatechartbutton=tk.Button(master=master,text='update plot',command=self.drawcustomplot)
        self.canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='x',expand=True)
        #self.canvas1.mpl_connect('pick_event',self.onpick)
        self.toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas1,master)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')
        self.updatechartbutton.pack(side='top')

    def drawcustomplot(self):
        customplot(self.f)
        plt.xticks([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])
        self.canvas1.show()

root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

*This code just starts up a tkinter with canvas widget that contains the figure, which is then updated when the button is pressed*

You'll notice in the `customplot` function I try to set `plt.xticks` to no avail. I realize this likely has something to do with declaring them using pyplot not correctly translating into a change in tkinter, but I'm not sure how to do it properly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Simply completely avoid using pyplot when embedding figures in tkinter. Don't import it, so you won't be tempted to use it. Instead, work on the objects like figure or axes directly.

Comment: Ah yes didn't realize i was still importing in that code snippet... originally i simply had `import matplotlib`, in retrospect though it was that I simply didn't understand (and still don't, but at least know) why the ticks and tick labels are referenced differently on axis themselves as @eyllanesc points out. Thanks for the heads up though, will save me headaches I'm sure as I'm just starting to learn about embedding plots.

Comment: `pyplot` has been designed to be closely related to the structure and syntax of matlab. However in the matplotlib API, most commands have a getter/setter syntax (`set_<property>`).

Comment: Ah ok, I naively have just used pyplot because it worked "out of the box" for plotting in notebook which is where I tend to test and write my code because of the modular format and user-friendliness, though never used matlab. I guess I might as well try to get used to the API commands to save myself going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `plt` you must use `ax` (AxesSubPlot object), in your case it changes:

```
plt.xticks([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])
```

to

```
ax.set_xticks([1,2,3])
ax.set_xticklabels(['one','two','three'])
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you. Does anyone have a good resource to better understand how these little intricacies of matplotlib work? They never really work quite how I'd think right off the bat.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really helpful. This is tkinter/Canvas embedded pyplot matplotlib/seabron. I changed the xticks and xticks labels position from decimal display into binary scale display using this ax.set_xtcicks (array) [set the position] and ax..set_xticklabels(text_array) [set the display labels, both dimensions needs to be the same].